# Python Flask "make_response" from string

Tags: python, flask

I have a string which contains a specific response. For example:

```
b'HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect\r\nServer: Http Server\r\nDate: Sun Jun  7 12:53:19 2020\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nLocation: http://192.168.3.1/main.html\r\n\r\n<html><head></head><body>\r\n\t\tThis document has moved to a new <a href="http://192.168.3.1/main.html">location</a>.\r\n\t\tPlease update your documents to reflect the new location.\r\n\t\t</body></html>\r\n\r\n'
```

And I want to build and return the response from this. Is there any way I can do that with a Flask function?

I already tried make_response function as such `return make_response(my_string)` but it returns:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 383
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.6.9
Date: Sun, 07 Jun 2020 12:32:05 GMT

HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect
Server: Http Server
Date: Sun Jun  7 12:53:19 2020
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://192.168.3.1/main.html

<html><head></head><body>
        This document has moved to a new <a href="http://192.168.3.1/main.html">location</a>.
        Please update your documents to reflect the new location.
        </body></html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking. Why is that response incorrect?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 200 OK instead of HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect, the question is about using a function to convert a string to a response instead to build a response and provide the string as body

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in a simple way with flask.

You have a *raw* HTTP response containing all the response headers and the HTTP contents in one string.

flask is a wsgi application returning headers and the response in separate fields and letting the wsgi server combine both.

Theoretically you could try to parse the string, split it into head fields and contents, return it and let the wsgi server recombine it to a string.
(potentially you could use libraries like `requests` and try to monkeypatch / mock it to do the parsing for you)

But this feels like a major patchwork and I wouldn't recommend it.

Perhaps you can explain the bigger context and we might come up with a solution that does what it wants, though it will probably not convert a string into a flask response that will be returned by the wsgi server.

Where did you / do you get the string from Couldn't you reveive it already as a parsed HTTP response?